# Inner join to create new column for view returns wrong values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with countries and regions that I would like to join on another table containing countries and population. All of that should be part of a view. The expected result when I run the query isolated is this:

```
SELECT d.country, c.region, d.population
FROM data d
INNER JOIN country_region c ON c.country = d.country
```

Result:

```
Country    Region          Population
France     Europe          70
Germany    Europe          80
Japan      Asia            130
Brazil     South America   200
```

Now when I run the same table to create my view, the inner join goes wrong and returns Europe for all countries and I can't figure out why.

```
CREATE VIEW data_consolidated AS
    SELECT 
        d.country,
        (SELECT region c
         FROM data d
        INNER JOIN country_region c ON c.country = d.country) AS region,
        d.population
    FROM
        data d
```

Result:

```
Country   Region   Population
France    Europe   70
Germany   Europe   80
Japan     Europe   130
Brazil    Europe   200
```

My source tables:

```
country_region
country   region
France    Europe
Germany   Germany
Japan     Asia
Brazil    South America

data
country   population
France    70
Germany   80
Japan     130
Brazil    200
```

Comment: There is no correlation with your outer table `data`, you do not need it in the sub query.

Comment: Why don't you use your working query to create the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub query needs to be correlated with the `outer reference`

```
CREATE VIEW data_consolidated AS
    SELECT 
        d.country,
        (SELECT region from country_region c where c.country = d.country) AS region,
        d.population
    FROM
        data d
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I just read up on correlated subqueries and their performance issues. Is there a way to rewrite this query with improved performance?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your first query, just use that. Both give identical results, both will probably produce the exact same execution plan, there probpably won't be any difference in performance. I'm not aware of any inherent performance issue with subqueries - performance always comes down to the table access methods chosen by the query engine, index utilization and join order to name a few.